# Comparing strings and extracting differences at the phrase-level in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I'm trying to compare two columns containing strings in a data frame and extract the differences. However all solutions I've seen extract differences at the character level, and I'm looking to extract entire words/phrases.  I have a dataframe set up like this:

```
TECH_ID YRTR    pre_drop_courses                post_drop_courses               unchanged
71795   20213   BUSN 2100,BUSN 2400,ACCT 2254   BUSN 1102,BUSN 1102,BUSN 1102   FALSE
71795   20183   BUSN 1102,BUSN 1102,BUSN 1102   BUSN 2100,BUSN 2400,ACCT 2254   FALSE
73677   20183   BIOL 2041,BIOL 2041,BIOL 2041   BIOL 2042,BIOL 2042,BIOL 2042   FALSE
73677   20193   BIOL 2042,BIOL 2042,BIOL 2042   BIOL 2041,BIOL 2041,BIOL 2041   FALSE
```

For rows that have differences between the pre_drop and post_drop columns I want to extract the entire course code that is different. Ideally I would have a column for what courses were dropped and what were added. For example in the first row BUSN 2100, BUSN 2400, and ACCT 2254 would all appear in the 'dropped' column, and BUSN 1102 would appear in the 'added' column. Likewise in the third row we would see that BIOL 2041 was dropped and BIOL 2042 was added.

Edited to show results of dput(head(mydata, 3))

```
structure(list(TECH_ID = c("00000108", "00000108", "00000270"
), YRTR = c("20173", "20173", "20183"), pre_drop_courses = c("MUSC 2231,MUSC 2281,MUSC 2231,MUSC 2281,MUSC 2231,MUSC 2281", 
"MUSC 2231,MUSC 2281,MUSC 2231,MUSC 2281,MUSC 2231,MUSC 2281", 
"ACCT 1853,ACCT 1853,ACCT 1853"), post_drop_courses = c("MUSC 2231,MUSC 2281,MUSC 2231,MUSC 2281,MUSC 2231,MUSC 2281", 
"MUSC 1116,MUSC 1116,MUSC 1116", "ACCT 1853,ACCT 1853,ACCT 1853"
), unchanged = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Just to make sure your data is what I think i is would you please edit your question to show the results of `dput(head(mydata, 3))`, thank you.

Comment: @ChuckP edited!

Comment: Thanks but why in row1 does the student have the same course listed 3 times?

Comment: @ChuckP this is likely because a student added/dropped a course multiple times and in an earlier dataframe they had multiple time stamps. So if a student added the course, dropped it, and added a difference section, it would show up as 3 separate instances. I plan on reducing duplicated course designations in a later step.

Comment: LOL this is why we love our "student information systems"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow me to handle the process of making the course list unique while I'm at it, since it makes the solution cleaner.

Load `stringr` to take out any unnecessary whitespace, and then split the string of courses into a vector of courses...

```r
library(stringr)
df$pre <- stringr::str_split(stringr::str_squish(df$pre_drop_courses), ",")
df$post <- stringr::str_split(stringr::str_squish(df$post_drop_courses), ",")
```

Use `Map` to get the unique values of courses for `pre` and `post`

```r
df$pre <- Map(unique, df$pre)
df$post <- Map(unique, df$post)
```

Use `Map` to find the set differences.  One direction is adds the other is drops

```r
df$dropped <- Map(setdiff, df$pre, df$post)
df$added <- Map(setdiff, df$post, df$pre)

df
#>    TECH_ID  YRTR               pre_drop_courses             post_drop_courses
#> 1 00000108 20173  BUSN 2100,BUSN 2400,ACCT 2254 BUSN 1102,BUSN 1102,BUSN 1102
#> 2 00000108 20173 BUSN 1102,BUSN 1102,BUSN 1102  BUSN 2100,BUSN 2400,ACCT 2254
#> 3 00000270 20183  BIOL 2041,BIOL 2041,BIOL 2041 BIOL 2042,BIOL 2042,BIOL 2042
#>   unchanged                             pre                            post
#> 1      TRUE BUSN 2100, BUSN 2400, ACCT 2254                       BUSN 1102
#> 2     FALSE                       BUSN 1102 BUSN 2100, BUSN 2400, ACCT 2254
#> 3      TRUE                       BIOL 2041                       BIOL 2042
#>                           dropped                           added
#> 1 BUSN 2100, BUSN 2400, ACCT 2254                       BUSN 1102
#> 2                       BUSN 1102 BUSN 2100, BUSN 2400, ACCT 2254
#> 3                       BIOL 2041                       BIOL 2042
```

Your original sample data

```r
df <- 
   structure(list(TECH_ID = c("00000108", "00000108", "00000270"), 
   YRTR = c("20173", "20173", "20183"), 
   pre_drop_courses = c("BUSN 2100,BUSN 2400,ACCT 2254", 
                        "BUSN 1102,BUSN 1102,BUSN 1102 ",
                        "BIOL 2041,BIOL 2041,BIOL 2041"), 
   post_drop_courses = c("BUSN 1102,BUSN 1102,BUSN 1102", 
                         "BUSN 2100,BUSN 2400,ACCT 2254", 
                         "BIOL 2042,BIOL 2042,BIOL 2042"
                                                             ), 
   unchanged = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE)), row.names = c(NA, 3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: That worked! However I have some added/dropped columns that have values like "MUSC 1116" and some that have c("MUSC 1116") - is there a way to convert these all to match?

Comment: Probably can I please see the data for one of the rows that is generating this odd value?

Comment: > dput(head(all_courses2, 1))
structure(list(TECH_ID = "00000108", YRTR = "20173", pre_drop_courses = "MUSC 2231,MUSC 2281,MUSC 2231,MUSC 2281,MUSC 2231,MUSC 2281", 
    post_drop_courses = "MUSC 1116,MUSC 1116,MUSC 1116", unchanged = FALSE, 
    added = list("MUSC 1116"), dropped = list(c("MUSC 2231", 
    "MUSC 2281")), pre = list(c("MUSC 2231", "MUSC 2281")), post = list(
        "MUSC 1116")), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")